# Django Select Related

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-select-related

i want to filter the database like this .

```
qs = profile.objects.filter().select_related('profile_detail').select_related('location')
```

But here location  is a foreignkey in profile_detail model. So how can i do that query

```
class Location(models.Model):
      place = models.CharField(max_length=128)

 class ProfileDetail(models.Model):
     location = models.ForiegnKey(Location)

  class Profile(models.Model):
      detail = models.ForeignKey(ProfileDetail)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use related lookup query syntax `__`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

```
qs = profile.objects.filter().select_related('detail__location')
```

And it should `detail` not `profile_detail`. Just as your field in `Profile` called

Comment: can we use related name instead of field name here . detail = models.ForeignKey(ProfileDetail, related_name="pdetail") 
qs = profile.objects.filter().select_related('pdetail__location')

Comment: @Thameem No. related name is used in reverse lookups. For example if you have `profie_detail` object. Then you can do this `profile_detail.pdetail.all()` to get all profiles with this `profile_detail`